# Visual Studio 2017 code compiles, but nuget packages are red underlined

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package-restore

After reinstalling my PC, including VS, my code compiles, but certain nuget packages' using statements (and thus, lines using the package too) are underlined with a red error as if the package was not referenced. However, the code compiles just fine. While this could be just an annoyance, pausing the code and modifying even just a space in a comment now does not let me continue like it used to.

I'm sure I'm just missing some cache clear somewhere, but so far I have not found a solution. VS clean/rebuild, clean and re-open VS, bin/obj folder deleting did not help, restoring nuget packages says there is nothing to restore.

Comment: May sound dumb but did you try restarting VS ? I get this quite often and restarting Visual Studio often resolves any UI Bugs..

Comment: How about Exit VS then open solution?

Comment: Edited my post, but yes, I did even clean and re-open VS.

Comment: Expand the references in the Solution explorer. and see if  some references have an warning sign next to it. If so, then I suspect these packages werent downloaded. Are they available at the repository from where you are downloading the nuget packages

Comment: VS 2017 15.8.3 with ReSharper 2018.2 also does this for me. Also, packages aren't always properly restored after switching branches. Restarting Visual Studio usually fixes it for me.

Comment: They are not marked with warning signs because they are downloaded. I assume my project would not compile otherwise.


I did not reinstall ReSharper yet, so it cannot be the issue.

Comment: I see this when using the new PackageReference instead of packages.config. Closing/re-opening solution fixes it. the new csproj doesn't detect changes from nuget

Comment: Closing/reopening the solution does not help.
Closing/reopening vs also does not help.

Comment: Are you using resharper?

Answer (score 7):

Try closing Visual Studio and then delete the .vs directory that is at the solution level. I had the exact same symptoms as you and that was the only thing that fixed it for me.

Comment: This fixed it for me, but it can also be that the HintPath in the csproj file is incorrect.  In my case, I had both problems.

Comment: Same issue exists 5 years later in VS2022 - obviously hasn't been addressed by Microsoft...